# PayPal Sandbox - CreateBillingAgreement call returns Internal Error (10001)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I'd appreciate any help with this, I've run around in circles trying all sorts of combinations with the PayPal Api - but I'm hitting a brick wall on this one.

I'm looking to call the CreateBillingAgreement method but each time I do it fails and reports a 10001 'internal error' from paypal in the response.
I have a valid token and I'm using version 84.0. I've successfully called SetupExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckout, both of which succeed and the payment goes through. I'm setting up a future payment / pre-authorisation on the SetupExpressCheckout and the user agrees to that no problems.

​Do I need to change settings on the merchant in the sandbox? Am I calling things in the wrong order maybe? (SetExpress, GetExpress, DoExpress, CreateBilling)?

​I'm looking to use this billing agreement to allow a reference transaction in the future. I'm having a test account 'pay' using paypal and not forwarding any credit card details, the payment is for a digital service with no delivery (no shipping is set, no addresses or delivery costs are involved). The overall goal is to provide a one-click re-order button, whereby no details need to be entered by the customer.

I'm using the C# api in asp.net 4, or more specifically I've created Service References from the paypal sandbox wsdl and I'm using those in asp.net.

​Any and all help is appreciated - thanks.

​Russell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call CreateBillingAgreement if you're specifying billingtype `MerchantInitiatedBilling` in your SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call. `CreateBillingAgreement` is only necessary if you don't want to call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`.
If `MerchantInitiatedBilling` is set, `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` will already return a billing agreement ID, which you can use in `DoReferenceTransaction`.

I don't have access to an example at hand, but will update this post as soon as I've found one for you.

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much. I wasn't getting the billing agreement ID in the do response, but then I hadn't set MerchantInitiatedBilling! :) 

thanks again Robert.